# Creating an entity data model correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

I am quite new to the entity framework and want to implement it in the best way. I'd like to know if the ideas I have are possible to implement and if they are best practice.

Model 1

What I would like here is basically to use the Orders and Addresses entities to be able to use the same lookup table. The idea with the lookup table is to be able to hide / show all the Orders or all the Addresses for a specific user by having a property in the lookup entity that is that can store collections of generic objects.

[Model 1 entity diagram](http://www.newtonfellowships.org/images/entity-model-1.png)

[image]

Model 2

This is very much the same principle as above except that this is using navigation properties rather than a scalar property. I think this is the correct way, but not sure if there are issues that I may encounter down the line.

Thanks for your help

[Model 2 entity diagram](http://www.newtonfellowships.org/images/entity-model-2.png)

[image]

=======Added 16/12/2013==============

I want to extend this model slightly further by having some inheritance for the user. Basically there are 3 different types of user that have the majority of properties for now, but in future they could have a few properties specific to them. To help achieve this I came up with the model below.

[image]

Now when I try to add a Fellow for example, it rightly complains that

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_HonoraryMemberLookup", which I assume means that it is trying to add a lookup for the two other user types, and cannot because of null values.

How would the lookup table need to be structured to avoid this error? Should I have separate lookup tables for each of the user types?

Thanks again

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're really optimizing here. A query to obtain a list of orders (or addresses) will now require two JOINs instead of one. Orders and Addresses are pretty orthogonal to one another, so it doesn't make much sense to use a single table inheritance hierarchy here. If the IsPublic field is a bit then you are optimizing to save a single bit per record. Hardly seems worth it.

Comment: Thanks Brian.

So what you're suggesting is having the IsPublic bool property on the Orders and Addresses entities? Makes sense but as there would be around 20 other entities that would need the IsPublic property which I why I was trying to declare it once. 

Thinking about it maybe I can have an entity with the field IsPublic and have the Orders and Addresses inherit it from this entity. Would that create any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use Table-Per-Type inheritance to achieve what you're looking to do. The model would look like this, with the Lookup entity marked as Abstract

[image: TPT Diagram]

Here is some example code that might use this model:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var container = new UserModelContainer())
        {
            var user = new User
                       {
                           FirstName = "Joe",
                           Surname = "Coder"
                       };

            var address = new Address
                          {
                              AddressLine1 = "123 Any Street",
                              AddressLine2 = "Apt 2A",
                              City = "Anytown",
                              StateProvince = "CA",
                              PostalCode = "12345",
                              Country = "United States",
                              IsPublic = false
                          };

            user.Lookups.Add(address);

            container.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var container = new UserModelContainer())
        {
            foreach (var user in container.Users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", user.FirstName, user.Surname);

                foreach (var address in user.Lookups.OfType<Address>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(address.AddressLine1);
                    Console.WriteLine(address.AddressLine2);
                    Console.WriteLine(address.City);
                    Console.WriteLine(address.StateProvince);
                    Console.WriteLine(address.PostalCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(address.Country);
                    Console.WriteLine("Address is {0}", address.IsPublic ? "Public" : "Private");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian this works really well. I've tried to extend this model slightly, please find details in the original post. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your Lookup entity should have a relationship only with the top-level User entity, not its derived types.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Normalizing your model will help you avoid storing the same piece of data several times (can lead to inconsistency) and reduce complexity.

It seems like you just want to connect a set of orders to a user, and a set of addresses to a user. For this, I'd go with something like Model 2, but without any Lookup table (connecting Addresses and Orders to the user table directly).

The only thing your Lookup table contains that gives it reason to exist is an IsPublic flag. What is it used for? If Lookups are things the user can create, save, and are generally aware of as a `thing`, then the Lookup table might be warranted, and I'd use Model 2. If the lookup table only exists to ease query creation, I'd rather skip it to keep the database model as simple as possible.

I haven't dealt with storing generic objects with EF myself, but this isn't something I've seen any relational database system do before, so I'd be wary of using it for portability reasons.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. 

The idea of the IsPublic flag was a way for the users to not have their information displayed on site per entity. 

There would  be lots of entities similar to the Addresses and Orders, all of them needing the IsPublic property I was trying to find a way to inherit this so I only have to declare it once.


From your response it sounds like it would be easier to have the IsPublic on each entity? I could then if the user decides not to show their Orders, loop through all their orders and set the IsPublic to false.

Comment: It seems like Brian Driscoll's answer is what you are looking for, assuming that one wants to specify IsPublic for each Order object, each Address object, etc.

If you want to specify IsPublic only for the categories (all Addresses, all Orders, etc.) then I would rather keep that information elsewhere - I'm not sure what would be most efficient, but a table with three columns: UserId, CategoryName, IsPublic would be sufficient for looking up which categories to show or not.